# Delete object reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new in js and angularjs and ran into some basic problem i can't solve.
I add the $scope.consignations to the view with ng-repeat. Its a big object with several layers. In the sample code, i assign the $scope.consignations to the temp and after that, i "navigate" inside the temp object and at some point i push data to the temp. It changes the view, as expected.Now i want to clear the $scope[elementName] obj, but it clears the pushed data as well from the view. I've tried to delete the temp reference (i assume its only a reference of the $scope.consignations obj.) and i cant access it anymore, but when i clear the  $scope[elementName] it clears the view anyway.

```
$scope.addElements = function(elementName){ 
    temp=$scope.consignations;

    for (var key in someArray) {
      //here i "navigate" recursive inside temp 
    }
    temp.push($scope[elementName]);
    delete temp;
    for (var key in $scope[elementName]) {
         $scope[elementName][key]="";
    }
};
```

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: What do you think `delete temp` is doing? The delete operator is only used to delete properties, not objects.

Comment: I want to update the  $scope.consignations with the temp, but after i've done it, i want to empty the  $scope[elementName] without any other changes in the $scope.consignations or the view.

Comment: temp=$scope.consignations; by doing so your temp & $scope.consignations references same object. So change in any object will be reflected in other and also in view. So you should copy it like $scope.temp=angular.copy($scope.consignations) and then use $scope.temp for view binding and $scope.consignations for other perpose.

Comment: But i need the reference for changing the view in the first place. After that, i want to cut the reference.

Comment: I think it's working. The solution was, that instead of temp.push($scope[elementName]); i had to use the copied version of it, so with the temp changes, i can change the $scope.consignations and with it the view but clearing the $scope[elementName] does not change anything.Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp=$scope.consignations` by doing so your `temp` & `$scope.consignations` references same object.
So change in any object will be reflected in other object as well as in view.

So you should copy it like `$scope.temp=angular.copy($scope.consignations)` and then use `$scope.temp` for view binding and $`scope.consignations` for other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an existing element from $scope to a new $scope variable and delete the old one then you can use the following approch.

```
$scope.consignations.push(angular.copy($scope[elementName]));
delete $scope[elementName];
```

Assuming $scope.consignations is you new array where you want to store the data and $scope[elementName] is your old one which you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using definedProperty, angular will not copy these.
[This snippet](https://gist.github.com/Mephiztopheles/6808d32196fc20871d4d) will help you out then.